# How to split value over time in PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a value that is valid for a period of time, for example, 1200 minutes overtime period of 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31.

format:
Start date, End date -> total time in minutes

```
2020-01-01, 2020-12-31 -> 1200
```

What's the best way to be able to split it by day/week/month (i have a calendar table ready)?

[image]

The end goal is to present it on the graph cumulatively as well as additional data from the other table that will show progress against this target.

Additional data is logged per day in the format:
DATE -> VALUE in minutes (not cumulative)

so (reflected in the 2nd chart below):

```
2020-02-05 -> 300 minutes
2020-05-22 -> 200 minutes
2020-07-12 -> 100 minutes
2020-09-02 -> 300 minutes
2020-10-05 -> 100 minutes
2020-11-09 -> 100 minutes
2020-12-12 -> 100 minutes
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an index column in your date table and then scale that one according to your desired trend:

```
Expected = RANKX ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Date], , ASC ) * 1200 / 366
```